# Display text from 3 different strings in string 4 separated by a blank

Tags: assembly, x86

I have 3 strings str1, str2, str3. Each string representing a line of text.

How to concatenate the texts from these strings in a str4, separating them by a blank, and to display all strings on the screen.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
 
.data
str1 byte "first string", 0
str2 byte "second string",0
str3 byte "third string", 0
str4 byte 33 dup (?)
 
.code
THELOOP proc
mov al, [esi]
mov [edi], al
inc esi
inc edi
loop THELOOP
RET
THELOOP ENDP
 
main PROC
mov edx, offset str1
call Writestring
call Crlf
mov edx, offset str2
call Writestring
call Crlf
mov edx, offset str3
call Writestring
call Crlf
lea esi, str1
lea edi, str4
mov ecx, sizeof str1
call THELOOP
 
lea esi, str2
mov ecx, sizeof str2
mov edi, offset[str4]+9
CALL THELOOP
 
lea esi, str3
mov ecx, sizeof str3
mov edi, offset[str4]+33
CALL THELOOP
mov edi, offset str4
call fnd
 
chng proc
mov al, "_"
mov [edi]-1,al
inc edi
jmp fnd
chng endp
 
fnd proc
mov al, " "
mov ecx, lengthof str4
repne scasb
jz chng
fnd endp
 
mov edx, offset str4
call Writestring
call Crlf
exit
main ENDP
END main
```

At the end of execution I have to get something like "first_stringsecond_stringthird_string"

This is what I am getting right now

[image: This is what I am getting right now]

Comment: Have you tried running this thru a debugger?  I suspect 'sizeof' may not be doing what you intend.  Also, after your first call to THELOOP, where is EDI pointing when you return?  It's pointing at the next byte after the end of the first string in str4, right?  Exactly where you want to write the space.  After you add the space, you can increment it and it will be pointing exactly where you want to start writing the next string.  You may also want to check the length you're using for str4.  Is that going to be big enough to hold all the previous strings (plus spaces, plus trailing null)?

Comment: `sizeof` should work just fine if this is MASM. But it probably includes the zero terminator, so after `THELOOP` has finished you'd have to `dec edi` before the next loop (and get rid of those explicit `mov edi, offset...` instructions).

Comment: Also, you could probably shorten the code a bit if you put the space-to-underscore conversion inside `THELOOP`.

Comment: I don't use sizeof or lenghtof .... you can do it using a counter started in zero, than you read a byte and compares it to zero, if not you increase the counter.. easier